# Detail of a proof "Sobolev inequality $\Rightarrow$ Isoperimetric inequality".

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, sobolev-spaces, surface-integrals

From:

> Sobolev inequality: For all $u\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ $$\|u\|_{L^{\frac{n}{n-1}}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq C \|\nabla u\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$$

I want to prove:

> Isoperimetric inequality: For every bounded open set $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ with boundary $\partial E$ of class $C^1$, $$|E|^{\frac{n-1}{n}}\leq C|\partial E|.$$

The idea is to put $u=\chi_E$ in the Sobolev inequality, because in such a case $\|u\|_{L^{\frac{n}{n-1}}(\mathbb{R}^n)}=|E|^{\frac{n-1}{n}}$ is the left hand-side of the isoperimetric inequality. The problem is that $\chi_E$ is not in the Sobolev space $W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Thus, we regularize via convolutions: define $u_\epsilon=\chi_E\ast \rho_\epsilon$, where $\rho_\epsilon(x)=(1/\epsilon^n)\rho(x/\epsilon)$, $\rho\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\text{support}(\rho)\subseteq B(0,1)$, $\rho\geq0$ and $\int \rho=1$. We have:
$$C\|\nabla u_\epsilon\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}\geq \|u_\epsilon\|_{L^{\frac{n}{n-1}}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\stackrel{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}{\longrightarrow} \|\chi_E\|_{L^{\frac{n}{n-1}}(\mathbb{R}^n)}=|E|^{\frac{n-1}{n}}.$$ We want to prove that $\|\nabla u_\epsilon\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq |\partial E|$ for all $\epsilon>0$. We use the following result:

> For all $v\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla v|\,dx=\sup\left\{-\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\nabla v\cdot X\,dx:\,X\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n),\,|X(x)|=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (X^i(x))^2\right)^{\frac12}\leq 1\right\}.$$

It suffices then $$-\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\nabla u_\epsilon\cdot X\,dx\leq |\partial E|$$ for all $X\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $|X|=(\sum_{i=1}^n (X^i)^2)^{\frac12}\leq 1$. We have, using integration by parts, $$-\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\nabla u_\epsilon\cdot X\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u_\epsilon\,\text{Div}X\,dx=\int_E \text{Div}X_\epsilon\,dx=\int_{\partial E}X_\epsilon\cdot\nu\,d\sigma,$$ where $(X_\epsilon)^i=\rho_\epsilon\ast X^i$. It suffices to see that $|X_\epsilon(x)|\leq 1$ using $|X(x)|\leq 1$. I was not able to prove this. Any idea?

Comment: A trivial comment: the assumption $0 \leq \rho \leq 1$ is immaterial. And also impossible to satisfy for large $n$.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz You're right. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hölder's inequality/the trivial bound $ \lvert \int fg \rvert \leq \lVert f \rVert_{\infty} \lVert g \rVert_{1}  $ gives
\begin{align} \lVert X_{\epsilon} \rVert_{\infty} &= \sup_x \left\lvert \int \rho_{\epsilon}(x-y)X(y) \, dy \right\rvert \\
&\leq \sup_x \left( \sup_y \lvert X(y) \rvert \right)\left\lvert \int \rho_{\epsilon}(x-y) \, dy \right\rvert \\
&= \sup_x \left( \sup_y \lvert X(y) \rvert \right)\left\lvert \int \rho_{\epsilon}(y) \, dy \right\rvert \\
&\leq 1
\end{align}
since both terms are now independent of $x$ and $\int \rho_{\epsilon} = \int \rho = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I write $|X(x)|$ I mean $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (X^i(x))^2\right)^{\frac12},$$ not supremums. I edited the question.

Comment: But if the supremum of something (in this case, the norm) is at most $1$, *a fortiori* the value of something (the norm here) at a particular point must also be at most $1$.

Comment: But I did not write $\sup|X|\leq 1$, I wrote $|X|\leq 1$, that is, $|X(x)|=(\sum_{i=1}^n (X^i(x))^2)^{1/2}\leq 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: @user39756 It's the same

Comment: @themaker Where is $\sum_{i=1}^n (X^i)^2$ in the answer? I see $$|X_\epsilon(x)|=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_\epsilon)^i(x)^2\right)^{1/2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \rho_\epsilon(x-y)X^i(y)\,dy\right)^2\right)^{1/2}\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \|X^i\|_{\infty}^2\right)^{1/2}.$$ Why is that $\leq1$? I know $\sum_{i=1}^n X^i(x)^2\leq 1$, not $\sum_{i=1}^n \|X^i\|_{\infty}^2\leq 1$.

Comment: @user39756 $\sum_i (X^i)^2$ appears in the answer as $|X(y)|$ in the third and fourth lines.

Comment: @user39756 If $|X(y)| \leq 1$ as in your hypothesis, then $1$ is an upper bound to the set $\{|X(y)|  | y \in \mathbb R^n\}$, so the supremum, being the smallest upper bound, has to be smaller than $1$.

Comment: @user39756 Here is the detail that I believe bridges the gap between Chappers answer and the pointwise bound on the $2$-norm of $X$. It is a slight refinement on the estimate in your comment above. Since $\rho_\epsilon(y) dy$ is a probability measure, for every $x$ we may apply Jensen's inequality $$|X_\epsilon(x)|^2
 =  
 \sum_{i = 1}^n \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n}\rho_\epsilon(y)X^i(x - y)\; dy\right)^2
 \leq  
 \sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{\mathbb R^n}(X^i(x - y))^2\rho_\epsilon(y)\; dy
 \leq  
 \sup_{z\in \mathbb R^n}|X(z)|^2\int_{\mathbb R^n} \rho_\epsilon(y)\; dy$$