# Isoperimetric problem using the Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev

Tags: geometry, inequality, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Based in this  post [G-N-S $\Rightarrow$ Isoperimetric Inequality in Euclidean Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2225244). With the Isoperimetric Inequality in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. How can answer the following question: Between all open bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with fixed volume ,which one has the smallest surface area? I know which the answer is the sphere, but i don't know how prove it. Any tips?

---

With the tips of Giuseppe and Guy , i imagine which the answer of my answer is prove that the inequality in the tagged post with the constant

$C=\frac{\mathcal{L}^{n-1}(\mathbb{S}^{n})}{\mathcal{L}^{n}(\mathbb{B}^{n})^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}$

right?

Comment: I like the notes of Brian Weber on this topic: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~brweber/Courses/2015/760/Math760.html (Supplementary Notes). The connection between Sobolev's inequalities and isoperimetric inequalities is the very first topic.

Comment: it seems the solution below it not clear to you

Answer (score 0):

From this book by [Cedric Villani Old and New](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf) page 571 you have that 
$$ \frac{|\partial B^n|}{|B^n|^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}\le \frac{|\partial A|}{|A|^{\frac{n-1}{n}}} $$

> Now what happens if $|A|= |B^n(r)|?$ clearly it follows that $$\color{red}{|\partial B^n(r)|\le |\partial A| ~~~\text{which prove your statement}}$$

Comment: I imagine that this inequality in the book of Villani is the same inequality in the tagged post, yes? In this the constant $C=\frac{\mathcal{L}^{n-1}(\mathbb{B}^{n}) }{\mathcal{L}^{n}(\mathbb{B}^{n})}$?

Comment: @C.Junior yes it is the same inequality