# Reference request for Isoperimetric Inequality using Sobolev inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I want to prove Isoperimetric inequality from Sobolev inequality. I have seen a post in stack , but I want to know if some proper reference exists which I didn't find yet which proves Isoperimetric inequality from Sobolev inequality without using Calculas of Variations. Any help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proof on 5.6.2 of Evans and Gariepy's Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions (revised edition) using Sobolev's inequality for BV functions:
There exists $C>0$ such that for all $f \in BV(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ we have
$$ \|f\|_{L^{\frac{n}{n-1}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} \leq C \|Df\|(\mathbb{R}^{n}).$$
This is Theorem 5.10.
Now, Theorem 5.11 states that the same constant satisfies
$$\mathcal{L}(E)^{\frac{n-1}{n}} \leq C \|\partial E\|(\mathbb{R}^{n}),$$
where $E$ is a bounded set of finite perimeter in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. To prove it, just apply Theorem 5.10 with $f=\chi_{E}$.

Comment: This is for BV function, for $W^1,1$ functions mollifying the characteristics function would work?

Comment: yes, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225244/detail-of-a-proof-sobolev-inequality-rightarrow-isoperimetric-inequality